# Filtering with null

Tags: angular, null

I am just starting with angular, and I am trying to learn angular with Tour of heroes project. I just wanted to clarify the logic behind this code:

```
get validator: ValidatorFn | null
get asyncValidator: AsyncValidatorFn | null
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)
ngOnDestroy(): void
viewToModelUpdate(newValue: any): void**
```

I don't understand what the `| null` mean, what is the logic behind filtering with null, why filtering with no value?

Comment: This is a [typescript union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). It means `validator` has a type of `ValidatorFn` or `null`

Answer (score 0):

`*:ValidatorFn | null` means it is of type `ValidatorFn` or of type `null`.

The example that is used here is called "Union Types". Sometimes you don't know in advance what type some property will be/return. It is possible you want to declare a function that returns a string or a number or a boolean or null. "Union Types" allow you to do this while still keeping some type safety.

This is a part of the Typescript "Advanced Types", you can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).